# Calculate sum of couple columns for all rows

Tags: r

So as the titles says I'd like to calculate the sum of certain columns in a data frame and reapeat this calculation for all rows.

I'd like to do that in three different ways. I know the easiest solution:

```
vec_summed <- rowSums(mtcars[, c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8)])
```

but how I can do that using `apply`. What is wrong with the one I tried:

```
vec_summed <- apply(mtcars, 1, function(x) sum(mtcars[,4:8]))
```

The last question is how to do that using loop. That's really important for me as well.

Comment: Just `apply(mtcars[,4:8], 1, sum)` With a loop, something like `temp <- setNames(numeric(nrow(mtcars)), row.names(mtcars)) ; for(i in 1:nrow(mtcars)) temp[i] <- sum(mtcars[i,4:8])`

Comment: In your attempt you are defining a function with argument `x` but not passing it inside the function, so inside the function you need to put `x` instead of `mtcars` like this `apply(mtcars, 1, function(x) sum(x[4:8]))` Although the more compact way to do this is in the above comment